# How to compute Silhouette score in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have the following clusters:

```
In [24]: Cluster1 =[[1,0],[1,1]]

In [25]: Cluster2 = [[1,2],[2,3.4],[1,1.03]]

In [26]: Cluster3 = [[3,1],[3,3],[2,1.0]]
```

What I want to is to calculate [Silhouette scoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_%28clustering%29).
How can it be implemented in Python. I mainly have problem in understanding the computation of *a(i)* and *b(i)*. The datum *i*, is it the vector e.g `[1,0]` or scalar e.g. 1 (element of vector)?

Answer (score 0):

i is one data point, which can be either a feature vector or scalar depending on your problem formulation. this is point which is clustered. so in your example, this is vector since you are working in 2D space.